# Time difference in SQL between two rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `eventdata` like this

```
Timestamp                 GUId      EventTypeId

2015-02-01 05:00:00       1100      E012-1
2015-02-01 05:30:00       1100      E012-2

2015-02-01 06:00:00       1100      E012-1
2015-02-01 06:20:00       1100      E012-2

2015-02-01 07:00:00       2200      E012-1
2015-02-01 07:15:00       2200      E012-2
```

Now corresponding to `Guid`, we have different `EventTypeId`. Now when I see `E012-2` to corresponding `E012-1` for a `GUID` (this could be different, for example sake I gave like this) I need a difference in Timestamp in  minutes.

Example: for first two rows, for `GUID=1100` it's 30. For the 3rd and 4th rows it's 20 minutes. for `Guid=1100` for 5th and 6th rows it's 15 mints for `Guid=2200`.

I am using MySQL.

Comment: How would you decipher the first and third row? They have the same GUID and eventtypeId, so how would you know to compare rows 1 and 2, and not 1 and 4?

Comment: @McAdam331 : Question is correct, but the requirement is like Guid could be the same n no of times, but only thing we need to see the values E012-1 and E012-2..basically we need to keep the order in asc way, than start comparing corresponding E012-2 for E012-1...if we see than time difference in minutes..